# Как реализовать такие характеристики недвижимости на WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Есть Агентство недвижимости и я не могу понять как реализовать такие характеристики.
[image: скрин]
Реализовываю остальную страницу с acf, но с этими элементами теряюсь.
нужно чтобы заказчик добавлял лейбл + велью характеристики + в идеале добавлял количество этих характеристик

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Repeater внутри которого будет 2 поля Text. Я же так понимаю что каждая характеристика должна быть уникальной?